# Is there instance Alternative ((->) r)?

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor

I got accustomed to using `a <> b` where `a` and `b` take arguments.

```
> const ["a"] <> const ["b"] $ True
["a","b"]
```

Why there is no `a <|> b` as well?

```
> const ["a"] <|> const ["b"] $ True

<interactive>:64:13:
    No instance for (Alternative ((->) Bool))
      arising from a use of ‘<|>’
    In the expression: const ["a"] <|> const ["b"]
    In the expression: const ["a"] <|> const ["b"] $ True
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = const ["a"] <|> const ["b"] $ True
```

Comment: How would you define `empty` for `(->) r`?  Its type would be `empty :: r -> a`, which is only satisfiable with `unsafeCoerce` or `undefined`.  You would need to provide this definition in order to construct an `Alternative`.  Beyond that, how would you define `<|>`?  Its type would be `(r -> a) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> a)`.  If you had the `Monoid a => a` constraint then the implementation would be straightforward, but to work with all `a` you would need to choose which argument to `<|>` to apply.  Which do you choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'd like to express something like "if the result type is `Alternative`, then a function returning that type is `Alternative` too". This isn't right, however, because only `* -> *` types can be `Alternative`.

We might try to remedy our problem by saying that the result type should be `f a` for some `Alternative f`, but that's still not good, because the type for which we'd like to define the instance also has to have kind `* -> *`.

Actually, we just want to define an `Alternative` instance for the composition of `((->) r)` and some `Alternative f`. We can generalize this notion slightly to the following:

```
import Data.Functor.Compose

instance (Applicative f, Alternative g) => Alternative (Compose f g) where
  empty = Compose $ pure empty
  Compose a <|> Compose b = Compose $ liftA2 (<|>) a b
```

Unfortunately there is already a different `Alternative` [instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) for `Compose f g` in the `transformers` library, and it clashes with the above instance.

Alternatively, we could notice that `ReaderT r m` is the same thing as `Compose ((->) r) m` (modulo `newtype` wrapping), and fortunately the right instance is already exported by `transformers`:

```
instance Alternative m => Alternative (ReaderT r m)
```

So we can do the following:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

runReaderT (lift ["a"] <|> lift ["b"]) True
-- ["a", "b"] 

runReaderT (empty <|> lift (Just 0)) True
-- Just 0
```

Comment: OP's choice of Alternative isn't very revealing, of course, since `<>` and `<|>` are both `++` for `[a]`.